# Using Cloud SQL (Postgres) in Cloud Function

Tags: python, postgresql, google-cloud-functions, psycopg2, google-cloud-sql

I'm trying to connect to Cloud SQL running PostgreSQL 11 using a Cloud Function Python script. Ideally, I want to connect to the DB using a simple `pandas.DataFrame.to_sql()` which requires a `sqlalchemy.create_engine()` to connect.

This is my current attempt (I've tried both with/without `/.s.PGSQL.5432` suffix):

```py
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://USERNAME:PASSWORD@/DB_NAME?host=/cloudsql/INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME/.s.PGSQL.5432')
engine.connect()
```

I also try the [code sample](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/functions/sql/postgres_sample.py) provided by [Google](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/sql#connecting_to_cloud_sql) which uses `psycopg2` directly but also didn't work

```
Error: function crashed. Details:
could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/cloudsql/vida-production:us-central1:vida-ops/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

### Edit:

Thanks [@kurtisvg](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57960418/2826067) for pointing this out. Since the Cloud Function is trying to connect to Cloud SQL that is on a different project. I have to add the Cloud Function's service account to IAM of the Cloud SQL project.

After setting IAM, the Python code I use to connect `sqlalchemy` engine to Cloud SQL is this:

```py
# Don't add the "/.s.PGSQL.5432 suffix" because it will already be added back automatically by the library...

engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://USERNAME:PASSWORD@/DB_NAME?host=/cloudsql/INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME')
engine.connect()
```

Comment: Are you using second generation cloud sql instances?  https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/sql#connecting_to_first_generation_cloud_sql_instances

Comment: @DougStevenson Yes, I've verified that I'm using second gen Cloud SQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to check the following things:

- Have the Cloud SQL Admin API enabled
- Make sure the Functions default service account has the `Cloud SQL Client` IAM role

If you are connecting between two projects, make sure to enable the Admin API and grant permissions (for both projects) to the Service Account that is running the function you are trying to connect from.

Comment: Thanks @kurtisvg, the Cloud Function and the Cloud SQL are in a different project. So after adding the service account to Cloud SQL IAM role like you suggested, it works!